# Rails 4 - Saving multiple value in JSON objects in one single form AND/OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This table is `tbl_notification`. Let say, I want to produce a JSON output something like this:-

```
[
  {
    "trigger_event":"ONE",
    "ptc":
    {
      "id":"184"
    },
    "message":"this is message"
  },
  {
    "trigger_event":"TWO",
    "ptc":
    {
      "id":"184"
    },
    "message":"sasasd",
    "remind_interval":"60",
    "document":
    {
      "id":""
    }
  }
]
```

So there is only 2 main objects in this JSON (:trigger_event[ONE] & [TWO]). ONE has 3 hash while TWO has 5 hash.

For the db side, im using PostgreSQL and the column call `message_notification` which is JSONB data format type.

The JSON output above is under `message_notification` column.

**Controller** (just pull out the json part)

```
def create
  @geofence.message_notification = {
    trigger_event: params[:ng_geofence][:trigger_event],
    ptc: params[:ng_geofence][:ptc],
    message: params[:ng_geofence][:message],
    remind_interval: params[:ng_geofence][:remind_interval],
    document: params[:ng_geofence][:document]
  }.to_json
end
```

**Model** (just pull out the json part)

```
def as_hash(format=:google)
  {
    trigger_event: trigger_event,
    ptc: { id: ptc },
    message: message,
    remind_interval: remind_interval,
    document: { id: document },
  }
end

TRIGGER_EVENTS = [
  ["ONE","ONE"],
  ["TWO","TWO"]
]
```

**View** (just pull out the json part)

```
<%= f.select :trigger_event, Ng::Geofence::TRIGGER_EVENTS, { prompt: "-- Choose" } %>
<%= f.input :ptc, collection: @pretrips, wrapper: false, label: false, selected: (x['ptc']['id'] unless f.object.new_record?), :include_blank => true %>
<%= f.input :message, as: :string, label: false, wrapper: false %>
etc
```

---

This above code is working if the `:trigger_event` is `select_tag`.

So now, I want to change the behavior from `select_tag` to `check_box` for `:trigger_event`, something like this (example):

```
<%= f.input :trigger_event['ONE'], as: :boolean, label: 'ONE' %>
<br/>
<%= f.input :trigger_event['TWO'], as: :boolean, label: 'TWO' %>
```

The reason is, i want to make AND/OR form which is, user can check to field form ONE or check for field form TWO or check both to field form ONE & TWO.

1. So if check ONE, `:trigger_event, :message & :ptc {:id}` will save.
2. If check TWO, `:trigger_event, :message, :ptc {:id}, :remind_interval & :document {:id}` will save.
3. IF check both (ONE & TWO), will produce similar like the JSON output above.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand what you find so complex about this scenario.

Given that there is nothing special about these checkboxes, just use HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="trigger_events[one]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="trigger_events[two]" value="1">
```

Then in your controller you can simply check which of the checkboxes has been checked and produce the corresponding JSON:

```ruby
def create
  trigger_events = []

  if params[:trigger_events][:one] == '1'
    trigger_events << {
      trigger_event: 'ONE',
      ptc: { id: 184 },
      message: 'this is message'
    }
  end

  if params[:trigger_events][:two] == '1'
    trigger_events << {
      trigger_event: 'TWO',
      ptc: { id: 184 },
      message: 'sasasd',
      remind_interval: 60,
      document: { id: '' }
    }
  end

  @geofence.message_notification = trigger_events.to_json
end
```

***P.S.*** As I don't completely understand what your values should be, I am just going to hardcore `ptc`s, `message`s and etc. Replace them with the corresponding `params`.

***P.P.S*** `:trigger_event['ONE']` is equivalent to `"trigger_event"["ONE"]` or with other words you are trying to get the symbol at index `"ONE"` of the string `"trigger_event"` which would result in `nil`.

For reference, `:trigger_event[0]` will produce `"t"` *(the first character of the symbol's name)*.